# Is Oskar Potiorek considered a suspect in the Archduke Ferdinand assassination?

Tags: world-war-one, assassination, serbia

I was looking just a tiny bit at the history leading up to the assassination generally blamed for the first World War.  The data seem so surprising I just have to ask what I'm missing...

Oskar Potiorek had some apparent *bona fides*:

- He is said to be the [target of the assassination plot before it switched to Ferdinand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhamed_Mehmedba%C5%A1i%C4%87).
- He was rabidly anti-Serb, to the extent of supporting tremendously oppressive laws against all organizations, while provoking [riots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Serb_riots_in_Sarajevo) that were a major step leading up to the modern war in Bosnia.
- I assume he would have had authority over prior prosecutions of Serb activists later involved in the plot.

On the other hand...

- He [ignored](https://aspectsofhistory.com/before-the-assassination-archduke-ferdinand-and-the-general/) an urgent report of an assassination plot two weeks in advance.
- He taunted the Archduke to ignore the first attack with a grenade saying "Do you think Sarajevo is full of assassins?", even while chivalrously encouraging the wife to stay at City Hall
- He "forgot" to inform the driver of a route change that would have made the car not pass by the shooter.
- He ordered the driver to turn around (apparently the car then stalled) *a few feet in front of the assassin*!
- He was the one in the car not shot.
- His role as a general in the war afterward was remarkably incompetent.

Now I'm not actually seeing a contradiction in these things.  A role in persecuting Serbs would have given him a chance (with a little legerdemain) to organize selected individuals into a plot.  What evaluation has been made of his involvement?

Comment: Never assume malice for things that can be explained by incompetence.

Comment: @Spencer: One of my favorite sayings, up until the summer of past year.

Comment: When something is not impossible, it doesn't make it a likely explanation.

Comment: @Lucian - Last year is good for the followup: "Sufficiently advanced incompetence is indistinguishable from malice."

Comment: "I should file an impotent and unheard protest regarding how this question was considered. " - If it is unheard, it is because it is filed in the wrong place.  [Meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/) is where the community discusses moderation policy and conventions, and protest there are likely to be heard.  I was not part of the moderation here, but my hypothesis is that the research and the question weren't the problem; I suspect that the problem arose when you used the term "a suspect" - which carries (IMO) lots of baggage.  Revision might reopen.

Comment: @MCW There is a diff between https://meta.history.stackexchange.com/ and https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/ (probably a 1-off typo, but if c&p then in need of correction?)

Answer (score 4):

> His role as a general in the war afterward was remarkably incompetent.

You answered your question yourself. The above description is very accurate of his entire career; remarkably incompetent. It certainly explains the points you raise:

> - He ignored an urgent report of an assassination plot two weeks in advance.
> - He taunted the Archduke to ignore the first attack with a grenade saying "Do you think Sarajevo is full of assassins?", even while chivalrously encouraging the wife to stay at City Hall
> - He "forgot" to inform the driver of a route change that would have made the car not pass by the shooter.
> - He ordered the driver to turn around (apparently the car then stalled) a few feet in front of the assassin!

Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oskar_Potiorek) mentions his incompetence:

*He was reportedly very zealous in his actions (multiple times he claimed "I was spared at Sarajevo so that I may die avenging it!"), **but was apparently an inept commander**.*